# How should we approach questions about a user's rant against a moderation action?

Tags: discussion, scope

Although this site mainly caters to moderators, anyone is still free to contribute.  A non-moderator may even have some good questions to ask.  However, this may not always be the case.

What if some frustrated users decide to complain here about moderation activity on any site, most-likely from an SE site?  Would they be valid if cleaned up nicely, or would they just be considered noise?

Comment: If a user complains, should be redirected to the respective meta, but if his complain is general scenario which we think may be helpful for the the future reference of other visitors, should be considered as on topic.

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Right, and if it's nothing short of a swearstorm, it should be flagged as offensive.

Answer (score 7):

I would say that they can stay as long as they are used as an example in service to a more general point that applies to community moderation in general, and not just SE.

**Bad:**

> Mean Mod X deleted my question just because I asked a [totally appropriate and on topic question]. How do I exact vengeance upon him for abusing his powers?

**Better:**

> I disagree with how a mod closed my [on topic question]. What is a fair and efficient mechanism for community members to dispute moderator actions?

**Best:**

> I disagree with how a mod closed my [on topic question], but our site does not have a mechanism to dispute mod actions. How should I go about proposing adding X to allow community members to dispute moderator actions in the future?

This would also apply to answers. SE policy is a valid source of guidance, but SE should not be the **only** source.

If this type of thing happens often enough, maybe it should be a custom close reason.

Answer (score 3):

I think it really depends if it is a complaint or a legitimate question about moderation.  If for example, a user asked "How can I best make my intentions clear to a moderator in situation "xyz"?" Then I think it is probably a fine question as it involves dealing with moderation issues and is relevant to the site.  If it is simply complaining about a moderator action, it is noise and should be closed and removed as such.

Comment: Perhaps this would be a good close reason to propose?